# ggplot2: trouble filling point when using stat_summary argument

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following code:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x=Species, y=Sepal.Length)) + 
stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom='point', size=2, fill='white')
```

I know there are probably other ways of plotting this mean using the `iris` data. For my own data, though, it is the only way.

PROBLEM: the code above doesn't give white-filled points, but solid black points. Is there ar way to set the fill-colour when using the `stat_summary` argument?

Thanks!

Comment: Use stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom='point', size=2, col = "white") instead

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either use `color` instead of `fill`

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x=Species, y=Sepal.Length)) + 
stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom='point', size=2, color='white')
```

or use a symbol shape that has a fill *and* a border color

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x=Species, y=Sepal.Length)) + 
stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom='point', size=2, shape=21, fill="blue", color="red")
```